# How to "keep" USDT tokens inside a smart contract?

Tags: ethereum, solidity

I wanted to ask if its possible to have a USDT tokens (like the standard smart contract's balance in Ether) inside my smart contract, and if it was possible to than swap it with the Ether inside the smart contract's balance (if possible using Uniswap; swapping both from ETH to USDT and viceversa).

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is entirely possible to store ERC20 token in any contract, since the balance of ERC20 token is only defined as a mapping of `mapping(address => uint256)` in the ERC20 contract.

However, since transferring ERC20 requires either you as the owner or you having the approval to transfer, you will need to give yourself, or the address executing transactions, allowance to transfer the ERC20 "stored" in the contract address, or otherwise, the ERC20 token will be stuck inside the contract.

For the swapping part, you can look into the interfaces of Uniswap and have your smart contract call to Uniswap for the swap.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I comprehended the part about the mapping for the balance of the token and for the swap on Uniswap, but I didn't understand how can I accept ERC20 tokens like USDT inside my smart contract (for example, I have the function 'deposit', which requires ERC20 tokens, and it will update the mapping dedicated to the balance; how should I implement this function?)

Comment: You would need to call `transferFrom` in ERC20 to transfer the token from the `msg.sender` to `address(this)`, which is the contract address, in the function. Note that you would also need to approve the contract to allow it to call `transferFrom` from your wallet.

Comment: You may refer to one of my practice projects from a long time ago (which is a bit outdated but the method stays the same), https://github.com/kennysliding/random-solidity/blob/master/timelock/contracts/Timelocker.sol, where I call `transferFrom` in the deposit function to transfer the ERC20 into the contract.

Comment: that's exactly what I meant, thanks

Comment: that's exactly what I meant, thanks